# How to dynamically get view's origin in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, view, frame, preference

**Background**

Using SwiftUI, I want to implement tutorial(Coach marks) functionalities for some view( like button, text, image and so on) which was defined without specifying origin and sizes
for modifier frame. especially such functionalities will be asked for several difference screen.

**My Test Code**

*1. Definition of PreferenceKey*

```
struct MyPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

2. main view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rating : Int = 3
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let origin = geometry.frame(in: .global).origin
            let size = geometry.frame(in: .global).size
            VStack {

                HStack{
                    Text("Test1")   // for testing following target,just add some view hierachy
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                    VStack{
                        Text("test2")
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.purple)
                        Text("")   // here is my target, i want to get the origin of this view
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 200)   // just for having spece to show value of frame
                            .background(Color.green)
                            .overlay(
                                GeometryReader { proxy in
                                    let frm = proxy.frame(in: .global)
                                    let size = proxy.size
                                    Color.clear.preference(key: MyPreferenceKey.self,value: proxy.frame(in: .global))
                                    Text(verbatim: "X=\(String(format: "%.2f",  frm.midX)) y=\(String(format: "%.2f",  frm.midY) ) width=\(String(format: "%.2f",  frm.width)) height=\(String(format: "%.2f",  frm.height))")
                                        
                                }
                               
                            )
                    }
                }
                .onPreferenceChange(MyPreferenceKey.self){
                    print("\($0)")
                }
                
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        }
        
    }
}
```

**3. Ran result (Xcode)**

[image]

**4.Ran result (Log)**

> (***89.83333333333331***, 127.16666666666669, 100.0, 200.0)

**5. Problem**

the view with green background says it's origin.x is 139, but logs printed above is 89 in modifier onPreferenceChange.

**My Question:**

1. how can i get real origin.x with 139 using like modifier onPreferenceChange.
2. is there a way to get value  shown by above Text view

thanks.

Comment: It's better to define the @State variable and set your frame inside the overlay, in which the geometry reader data is not refreshing or changing the page anymore. Also, if you want to get the frame data inside a list, you can use a dictionary [Int:CGRect] to store each view based on its id.

Comment: @SajjadSarkoobi Thats interesting ... how does the dictionary [Int:CGRect] for a List work exactly?

Comment: @ChrisR this is a sample of how I used Dictionaries to store each view frame inside a dictionary. For time complexity, dictionaries are so optimized O(1). so we can get data from them very fast. https://github.com/sajjadsarkoobi/SnappingScrollView-SwiftUI

Comment: @SajjadSarkoobi   thanks for your idea,  i will try it when i have time. thanks again.